# Hello. My strips are suddenly unlabeled. How do I get the labels back onto my strips? Thank you

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Incredibly new to this. A minute ago the strips were labeled, and would display a waveform. I messed around with some settings, and now I can't get the labels back onto my strips. PLease help me get the labels back onto my strips. Thank you.

!(https://ibb.co/74w4LcY)

Comment: This Is The Problem https://ibb.co/74w4LcY

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: It's generally recommended that in the case where you find the answer yourself, to go ahead and provide an answer to your own question - using the designated answer field - so that others who have the same problem can potentially find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's the new 2.92 overlay options:

[image]